# Couldn't use integer as a key in associative array PHP

Tags: php, string, integer, associative-array

I want to use an integer as key in an associative array. I tried using settype() method to convert it to string and then merge it with an existing associative array

Here is the code:

```
$Xcenter = 325;
$Ycenter = 59.8;

$Xcenter = strval($XCenter);
$existing_array = array('a'=>'b', 'b'=>'c');
$new_array = array($XCenter=>$YCenter);
$result = array_merge($existing_array, $new_array);
print_r($result);
```

Current Output:

```
Array ( [a] => b [b] => c [0] => 59.8 )
```

Expected Output:

```
Array ( [a] => b [b] => c [325] => 59.8 )
```

For some reason it is not converting integer to string. But this is working perfectly fine for float values like the one below:

```
Array ( [a] => b [b] => c [148.33333333333] => 59.8 )
```

Comment: From where does: `$YCenter` come from ? Also just remove your settype call!

Comment: What about using `$Xcenter = "325"` instead of `settype()`?

Comment: What about just `$existing_array[$Xcenter] = 'something';` `array_merge` will reindex numeric keys, which is why you get 0.

Comment: As per the [docs](http://php.net/array_merge), `Don't forget that numeric keys will be renumbered`. doesn't matter if you forced `325` to be a string, it'll still be passed through is_numeric() and end up being treated as a number. Try `$result = $old_array + $new_array` instead.

Comment: @Rizier123 Your question makes less sense to me coz  YCenter is a value and it has got nothing to do with the way the key is indexed. I've replaced settype() with strval

Comment: @MarcB Thanks for the headsup man. Using $result = $old_array + $new_array instead of array_merge worked

Answer (score 4):

From the manual for [array_merge](http://www.php.net/array_merge):

> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value
>   for that key will overwrite the previous one. If, however, the arrays
>   contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original
>   value, but will be appended.
>
> Values in the input array with numeric keys will be renumbered with
>   incrementing keys starting from zero in the result array.

If you want to just set a key to a specific value, you don't need to merge, you can just set it like `$array[123] = $foo`. Or do a union with `$array1 + $array2`. But just an FYI, a union will not re-index numeric keys and it will not overwrite previous values. So you typically have to reverse the arguments that you would normally pass to array_merge. So `array_merge($a1, $a2)` is pretty much the same as `$a2 + $a1` without the re-indexed numeric keys.

Comment: Is the above statement true even if I convert the integer to string before I store it in the associative array ? Sure I will change the array_merge statement to like the one you have mentioned.

Comment: Given the result you are seeing, yes, strings with integer values will be renumbered. The manual states `numeric keys will be renumbered`. It likely just does an internal call to `is_numeric($key)` and if that is true, converts it to a number. Assuming there is an additional check that converting to an integer doesn't truncate the value like a float would like `if(is_numeric($key) && ((int)$key == $key)) /*re-index*/`